# Bing Music Search (shazam-like) gone

Tags: lumia, music, nokia-lumia-1020

I've recently bought a Lumia 1020 and started playing with the pre-installed apps. At some point I tested the Music Search app (I believe it's called that way) but after finding one song, the app simply ceased to exist.

I returned to the Search (via the search "button", where this app used to live) but I only got the QR reader there.

Here is a screenshot that might help:

[image]

Comment: Search is still there on my 1020.. Try a soft reset and if that doesn't work do a hard reset.

Comment: Did you changed region?

Comment: The region was changed when i first "logged in" on the phone, after buying it. Strange fact is that i ran it twice (the music app) but only after the second time it disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

The visibility of that feature is controlled by your "Browswer & Search Language".

I don't know why it dissapeared so all of a sudden. But if you try to change it to for example "English (United States)" and then press search it should appear for you.
You could then try to go back to you're original language to verify if it dissapeared again.

I tend to have my "Browser & Search Language" always set to US (even though I live in Sweden) just because it seems to bring more features and no limitations.